# Is there possible to use in CASE statement in WHEN more columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm trying to write something like this:

```
case column_01
    when column_01 = 5 AND column_02 = 'NO'
    then value
    else value_other
end
```

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: You are mixing two different case versions here.

Comment: You can find some additional information here http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=206

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed the two different **syntax** for **CASE** expressions.

You could do it as:

```
CASE
WHEN column_01 = 5 AND column_02 = 'NO' THEN
  value
ELSE
  value_other
```

**1. simple_case_statement**

```
   CASE [ expression ]

   WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN condition_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

   END
```

**2. searched_case_statement**

```
CASE 

   WHEN expression condition_1 THEN result_1
   WHEN expression condition_2 THEN result_2
   ...
   WHEN expression condition_n THEN result_n

   ELSE result

END
```

Comment: alternatively: `when (column_01, column_02) = ((5, 'NO')) then ...`

Answer (score 1):

With case statements, you either check for the value of one column/variable and do your checks against that:

```
case column_01
  when 1 then 'a'
  when 2 then 'b'
  ...
  else 'zzz'
end
```

or you check for conditions in each when clause:

```
case when column_01 = 5 and column_02 = 'NO' then value
     when column_01 = 10 and column_03 = 'FRED' then 123
     else value_other
end
```

You can't combine the two forms, nor does it make sense to do so.

Answer (score 0):

No. You must write a case statement for each column.